# Следить за изменением primary selection

Tags: linux, xorg

Здравствуйте. На просторах интернета довольно давно гуляет скрипт, позволяющий переводить выделеный текст в любом приложении. Алгоритм прост - по вызову скрипта считываем содержимое primary selection (xsel в помощь), отправляем запрос гугловскому переводчику и выводим результат через, например, notify-send. Как вызывать этот скрипт автоматически при изменении primary selection?

Comment: *скрипт* -- скрипты, десятки их :) Сам штуки три написал, для яндекса тоже. Там в простейшем случае писанины - 3-4 строчки. Но есть и понавороченей. А по сути - да тупо зациклить, с какой-то периодичностью проверять теукщее выделение и сравнивать с предыдущим. Только вот польза от этого очень сомнительна, вреда видится больше...

Comment: стоит оговориться, что отсылать всё что выделяешь гуглу — не самая светлая мысль...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ,а это вы точно подметили. Параноик во мне что-то раслабился)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На примере Яндекса:

```
#!/bin/bash

key="ваш ключ"
old="$(xsel -o)"
new=""

while true; do
  new="$(xsel -o)"
  if [ "$old" != "$new" ]; then
    old="$new"
    translated="$(wget -qO - "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=$key&text=$new&lang=ru")"
    notify-send -u critical "$new" "$(echo $translated | sed 's/.*\[\"\(.*\)\"\].*/\1/')"
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: `sleep` хотя бы за `if` вынеси...

Comment: Да, оно. Как подметили в комментарии к вопросу, использовать этот скрипт на постоянной основе не стоит. Но, например при чтении длинного текста на не совсем непонятном языке, очень даже подходит

Comment: @Fat-Zer, точно, на коленке набросал, ошибся :)